# DB normalization fails with first_or_create or faulty assignments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This question is apparently trivial, but I am a newbie in Rails and I can't figure out where I get it wrong. I am populating associated models from an old spreadsheet. Below is a rake import task snippet. Somehow when location (Washington) is the same and already exists in the database for the Smith's post, the new assignment made for a second record `post.locations << location` removes the location association with the Jones's post. My idea was to associate that same location with both people's posts. What am I missing?

**import.rake**

```
data = [
  { name: 'Jones',
    post: 'President',
    city: 'Washington'
  },
  { name: 'Smith',
    post: 'Vice-President',
    city: 'Washington'
  },
  { name: 'Peters',
    post: 'Janitor',
    city: 'New York'
  }
]

data.each do |row|
  name = row[:name]; post = row[:post]; city = row[:city]
  person = Person.where(name: name).first_or_create
  post = Post.where(post: post).first_or_create
  location = Location.where(city: city).first_or_create
  post.people << person
  post.locations << location
  location.save; person.save; post.save
end
```

The import above results in

```
person1 = Person.find_by_name("Jones");
person1.posts.first.locations.first == nil
person2 = Person.find_by_name("Smith");
person2.posts.first.locations.first.city == "Washington"
person3 = Person.find_by_name("Peters");
person3.posts.first.locations.first.city == "New York"
```

**location.rb**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :city
end
```

**person.rb**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :occupations
  has_many :posts, through: :occupations
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post
  has_many :occupations
  has_many :people, through: :occupations
  has_many :locations
end
```

**occupation.rb**

```
class Occupation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :person_id, :post_id, :since, :till
end
```

Comment: Use `save!` (with the bang), which will return an error instead of silently failing. Then you'll be able to see why/if something isn't saving.

Comment: Also might help to see your Occupation class.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and I keep checking. The data actually gets saved. The consequent save REMOVES the association from the first post when assigning the same location to the second post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if I understand your models correctly, then I think this is the issue...

You have a One-to-Many association between `Location` (many) and `Post` (one). When you say `post.locations << location`, what Rails is doing is finding that `location` and updating its `post_id`, therefore overwriting whatever you had there before. What you probably want is a Many-to-Many, so that a Post can have several Locations and vice-versa.

There are two ways to set that up: `has_and_belongs_to_many`, or `has_many :through`. The latter is generally better because it's more flexible, but for now I'll just show the easier method:

```
class Post
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end

class Location
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

create_table :posts_locations, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :post_id
  t.integer :location_id
end
```

The join table gets updated automatically with ID pairs that associate a Post with a Location when you do something like `post.locations << location` or `location.posts << post`.

Comment: Great notice! I wonder now if I should remove the question, since it is that obvious (and me being that inattentive) :)

Comment: No way - leave it, someone else will certainly come across it when they run into the same problem.